# I can not take result of my function

Tags: c#

I can not take result of my function.it works for if 1 and 2 but for third one it dose not work. it just print 2 to 9 as result it should solve an equation in function and give me the result but it does not work.can you tell me what is wrong with this?

```
class Program
{
    public double tri(double a,double b,double c,double d,int n)
    {
        double[] w = new double[10] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        int m = n - 2;
        double result = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= m; i++)
        {
            b = (b - c) * (a / b);
            d = (d - d) * (a / b);
            w[i] = d / b;
         }
         for (int j = m ; j <= 1; j--)
         {
             w[j] = (d - w[j + 1] * c) / b;
             result = w[j];
         }

         return result;
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int n = 10;
        double dif_co = 0.00000036;
        double t_int = 0.1;
        double s = 0.117;
        double n_dis = 1.111;
        double[] temp = new double[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        double a, b, c, d;

        Program heat = new Program();
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            if (i == 1)
            {
                a = 0;
                b = 1;
                c = 0;
                d = 700;
                temp[0]=700;
                Console.WriteLine("temprature is {0}", temp[0].ToString());
            }
            else if (i == n)
            {
                a = 0;
                b = 1;
                c = 0;
                d= 300;
                temp[9]=300;
                Console.WriteLine("temprature is {0}", temp[9].ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                a = -((2 * dif_co * t_int) - s * n_dis * t_int);
                b = (4 * (t_int * t_int)) + 4 * dif_co * t_int;
                c = (2 * dif_co * t_int) + (s * n_dis * t_int);
                d = ((2 * dif_co * t_int) * 300) + ((4 * (n_dis * n_dis) - 
                    (4 * dif_co * t_int)) * 300) + ((2 * dif_co * t_int) 
                    + (s * n_dis * t_int) * 300);

                temp[i] = heat.tri(a, b, c, d, n);
                Console.WriteLine("Temprature is {0}", i, temp[i].ToString());
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using a debugger and carefully crafting your code in small chunks so that it grows into what you finally need. the first error I spotted is that you have an invalid countdown loop

```
for (int j = m ; j <= 1; j--)
```

should read

```
for (int j = m ; j >= 1; j--)
```

i.e. m is assumed to be greater than 1 so in your code th loop will never execute.

the second thing I spotted is that you are using the value d as a multiplier in your **tri** function but you set d in a loop to (**d - d**)  * something else - can you spot the obvious error?

Didn't go searching for anything else but I strongly suggest you name you variables something meaningful "a, b, c, d ..."  make bug-finding far more difficult than it should be.